# how can i create checkbox on pdf using Itext7 C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I am very new to c# and trying to implement a check-box inside a pdf using itext7 . I am trying to use the documentation but keep getting error that "PdfButtonFormField in explicit interface declaration is not an interface"

```
virtual iText.Forms.Fields.PdfButtonFormField iText.Forms.Fields.PdfButtonFormField.SetRadiosInUnison   (bool radiosInUnison)
```

anyone can help me please to understand how to create the checkbox ? thank you

Comment: If it is going in a PDF document, I BET you could do it as simple as using a given letter from the WingDings1 font (lower x is a box with square, lower o is a open sqaure, no check or "x" within it.  Sure there are other means too.  Wingdings 2 see upper case QRST.

Answer (score 2):

Use the PdfFormField class to get a checkbox

```
PdfButtonFormField checkBox = PdfFormField.CreateCheckBox(pdf, new Rectangle(524, 600, 16, 16), "UsersNo", "Off", PdfFormField.TYPE_CHECK);
```

Full implementation to create a PDF file with just a single checkbox:

```
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;

PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("demo.pdf");
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);

PdfButtonFormField checkBox = PdfFormField.CreateCheckBox(pdf, new Rectangle(524, 600, 16, 16), "UsersNo", "Off", PdfFormField.TYPE_CHECK);
var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
form.AddField(checkBox);
document.Close();
```

Comment: `FabioStein`, your code works fine, but `new Rectangle` should be modified to `new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle`. When your code is used on other platforms, such as `Windows Forms`, the compiler confuses `new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle` with `System.Drawing.Rectangle`.